# IO_STALL question and understanding

Tags: sql-server, performance

I am collecting IO_STALLS from sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats every 5minutes and then doing a delta to see which files are being affected most by IO.

In one 5min period I get a delta of 5826331 ms which is 97minutes.

I am a little confused by this, is this saying that an operation started 97mins ago only just finished at that point and hence recorded that wait time?

Thanks

Added code as requested:

```
/*

USE [SysDBA]
GO
*/
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[DISKIOPS]    Script Date: 04/07/2013 11:40:15 ******/
/*
DROP TABLE [dbo].[DISKIOPS]
GO
*/
--Create the table
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[DISKIOPS]    Script Date: 04/07/2013 11:40:15 ******/
/*
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DISKIOPS](
    [IO_STALL] [bigint] NULL,
    [IO_STALL_READ_MS] [bigint] NULL,
    [IO_STALL_WRITE_MS] [bigint] NULL,
    [NUM_OF_READS] [bigint] NULL,
    [NUM_OF_WRITES] [bigint] NULL,
    [SIZE_ON_DISK_MB] [bigint] NULL,
    [DBNAME] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [NAME] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [FILE_ID] [int] NULL,
    [DB_FILE_TYPE] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [DISK] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [FILE_LOCATION] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [TIMESTAMP] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

*/

--Capture IO information from DMV and query to find deltas over time.
/*
USE [SysDBA]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[DISKIOPS]
           ([IO_STALL]
           ,[IO_STALL_READ_MS]
           ,[IO_STALL_WRITE_MS]
           ,[NUM_OF_READS]
           ,[NUM_OF_WRITES]
           ,[SIZE_ON_DISK_MB]
           ,[DBNAME]
           ,[NAME]
           ,[FILE_ID]
           ,[DB_FILE_TYPE]
           ,[DISK]
           ,[FILE_LOCATION]
           ,[TIMESTAMP])
SELECT a.io_stall, a.io_stall_read_ms, a.io_stall_write_ms, a.num_of_reads, 
a.num_of_writes, 
--a.sample_ms, a.num_of_bytes_read, a.num_of_bytes_written,
( ( a.size_on_disk_bytes / 1024 ) / 1024.0 ) AS size_on_disk_mb, 
db_name(a.database_id) AS dbname, 
b.name, a.file_id, 
db_file_type = CASE 
                   WHEN a.file_id = 2 THEN 'Log' 
                   ELSE 'Data' 
                   END, 
UPPER(SUBSTRING(b.physical_name, 1, 2)) AS disk_location,
b.physical_name AS File_location,
GETDATE() AS Timestamp
FROM sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats (NULL, NULL) a 
JOIN sys.master_files b ON a.file_id = b.file_id 
AND a.database_id = b.database_id
GO
*/
DECLARE @File_Name VARCHAR(8000),
        @Disk VARCHAR(5)
SET @File_Name = 'DBTEST'
SET @Disk = 'I:'
--Code to pull out deltas between collected IO stats.
;WITH IOPS   ([IO_STALL]
           ,[IO_STALL_READ_MS]
           ,[IO_STALL_WRITE_MS]
           ,[NUM_OF_READS]
           ,[NUM_OF_WRITES]
           ,[SIZE_ON_DISK_MB]
           ,[DBNAME]
           ,[NAME]
           ,[FILE_ID]
           ,[DB_FILE_TYPE]
           ,[DISK]
           ,[FILE_LOCATION]
           ,[TIMESTAMP]
           ,[ROW])
AS
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FILE_LOCATION ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC) AS [ROW]
FROM dbo.DISKIOPS 
)

SELECT MAX([IO2].[IO_STALL] - [IO1].[IO_STALL])
FROM IOPS IO1 JOIN IOPS IO2 ON IO1.ROW = (IO2.ROW+1)
WHERE IO1.NAME = IO2.NAME
AND IO1.Disk = @Disk
```

Comment: `io_stall` by itself doesn't mean too much.  If in 10 seconds you had 1000 operations stalling for 1 second each, you'll have 1000 seconds of stalls.  That would be 16+ minutes of stalls in 10 seconds.  You need to correlate this with IO operations.  Can you post your actual query in your question?

Comment: Hi there I have added the code, I was having a bit of trouble getting it to format so I hope its ok.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Question comment pasted below:

> `io_stall` by itself doesn't mean too much. If in 10 seconds you had 1000 operations stalling for 1 second each, you'll have 1000 seconds of stalls. That would be 16+ minutes of stalls in 10 seconds. You need to correlate this with IO operations...

The above is a pretty good example of how you can see monumental and seemingly exaggerated numbers.  By itself, `io_stall` doesn't really mean anything.  You need to know the scale of I/O operations for that cumulative stall.

Instead of having this:

```
SELECT MAX([IO2].[IO_STALL] - [IO1].[IO_STALL])
FROM IOPS IO1 JOIN IOPS IO2 ON IO1.ROW = (IO2.ROW+1)
...
```

You need to divide the stall by I/O operations to get the average stall per I/O (or per read, or write, or whatever granularity you're looking for).  In other words, my recommendation would be to modify your query to look something like this:

```
SELECT
    MAX(([IO2].[IO_STALL] - [IO1].[IO_STALL]) / (IO2.NUM_OF_READS + IO2.NUM_OF_WRITES - IO1.NUM_OF_READS - IO1.NUM_OF_WRITES))
FROM IOPS IO1 JOIN IOPS IO2 ON IO1.ROW = (IO2.ROW+1)
```

And then you need to have an extra predicate clause to ensure you're not dividing by zero:

```
...
WHERE IO1.NAME = IO2.NAME
and (IO2.NUM_OF_READS + IO2.NUM_OF_WRITES - IO1.NUM_OF_READS - IO1.NUM_OF_WRITES) > 0
AND IO1.Disk = @Disk
```

What this basically does is calculate the **average `io_stall` per I/O operation**.  By itself, a high `io_stall` could simply mean a higher workload and not necessarily the sign of a problem.

Comment: Ah right I understand, thanks very much, hopefully my mistake will prove useful to others.

Comment: It's a common mistake, not only with virtual file stats but also wait stats.  Glad it helped!